# Part specification error with InterpolatingFunction when generating a Markov Modulated Poisson Process

Tags: markov-chains, list-manipulation, random

I want to create a Markov Modulated Poisson Process, where the arrival rates created by the states of a `ContinuousMarkovProcess` are fed into an `InhomogeneousPoissonProcess`.

A simplified version looks like this:

```
CirculantMarkovModulatedPoissonProcess[time_] := Block[{λ, cmp},
  λ = {12, 32};
  cmp = RandomFunction[ContinuousMarkovProcess[1, ( {
       {-1, 1},
       {1, -1}
      } )], time];
  RandomFunction[
   InhomogeneousPoissonProcess[
     λ[[First[cmp["SliceData", t]]]], t], time]
```

The `InhomogeneousPoissonProcess` (IPP) evaluates a function of t for its arrival rates, the `ContinuousMarkovProcess` (CMP) transitions beetween different states that need to be mapped to the arrival rate.

Now the function works if I use the CMP states function straight as input to the IPP:

```
CirculantMarkovModulatedPoissonProcess[time_] := Block[{λ, cmp},
  λ = {12, 32};
  cmp = RandomFunction[ContinuousMarkovProcess[1, ( {
       {-1, 1},
       {1, -1}
      } )], time];
  RandomFunction[
   InhomogeneousPoissonProcess[First[cmp["SliceData", t]], t], time]
```

But I need to use the `cmp["SliceData", t]` as an index of the arrival rate stored in `λ = {12, 32}`.

If I evaluate the first function I get:

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression \[Piecewise]  1 TemporalData`InAbsoluteTime[t]==468393208/15237317
InterpolatingFunction[{{-(468393208/15237317),0}},{5,3,0,{35},{1},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{-(468393208/15237317),-(313637311/10531317),-(98033612/3321215),-(2109781963/72843953),-(317441493/11577172),<<25>>,-(90692477/35044868),-(131148145/59574359),-(85230605/80992003),-(22210743/163457482),0}},{{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1},{2},{1}},{Automatic}][-<<1>>] <<1>>

cannot be used as a part specification. >>
```

How do I select or "map" the CMP state as index to the list of arrival rates?
I wonder if I have to hold or evaluate any of those values early?

Thanks for your help and any suggestions!

**UPDATE**
In short: The `Part` of is pulled into the `InterpolationFunction` of the Markov Process. The solution is to evaluate it delayed with `SetDelayed` and restrict the input parameters to `NumericQ` as the accepted answer points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still on V10.0.2, so I can't test this with `InhomogeneousPoissonProcess`, but I think the following approach should work:

```
CirculantMarkovModulatedPoissonProcess[time_] := Block[{lambda, intensity, cmp},
   lambda = {12, 32};
   cmp = RandomFunction[ContinuousMarkovProcess[1, ( {
        {-1, 1},
        {1, -1}
       } )], time];
    intensity[t_?NumericQ] := cmp["PathFunction", 1][t] /. 
       MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Range[1, 2], lambda}];
    RandomFunction[
       InhomogeneousPoissonProcess[intensity[t], t],time]]
```

*Revised description, post bug-fixing edit*

The approach is fairly straightforward. The `"PathFunction"` property returns a 0-th order `InterpolatingFunction` object which shows the time evolution of the `ContinuousMarkovProcess`, like so:

[image: State evolution of 2-state continuous Markov Process]

This is almost exactly what we want for our intensity function for the `InhomogeneousPoissonProcess`; we only need to map the output so that `1 -> lambda[[1]]` and `2 -> lambda[[2]]`.  There are many ways this could be done; here I've chosen to use `MapThread` to create the requisite set of rules from the states `{1,2}` onto `lambda = {12,32}`.  For only two states, this is overkill, but it easily scales to larger, more general, combinations of state and rate vectors. This is largely a matter of programming style and taste --other approaches, such as those using `Part` are equally viable.

The `intensity` function defined within the block effectively implements this remapping of the output from the `"PathFunction"` onto our desired Poisson rates. The combination of `SetDelayed` and the restriction to `Numeric` is necessary here to prevent the rules from modifying internal parameters of the `InterpolatingFunction` before it is evaluated, e.g., the mapping `1 -> 12` would cause the requested `InterpolationOrder` to change from 0 to 11!

We then should be able to use the new intensity function in the `InhomogeneousPoissonProcess`. As noted, I don't have v10.1 so I can't test to be sure, but provided that it does not do something strange with the way it evaluates its inputs, this should work.

It is not necessarily the most elegant solution, but hopefully effective for your purposes.  My apologies for the bug in my initial answer -- hopefully this fixes things!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I tested it now. With `time == {0,5}` the process evaluates but with an error: `InterpolatingFunction::inhr: Requested order is too high; order has been reduced to {6}.`. When I try to evaluate up to, e.g. 30, the evaluation completely stalls. I can't figure out why I need a MapThread there, could you be so kind and give me an idea?

Comment: Thomas.  Sorry about that. I tested the state remapping with `Plot`, and things worked fine -- but `Plot` holds its arguments unevaluated.  That gives me a clue of how to fix it.  Give me a moment, and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm! I think the key point was the `SetDelayed` of the intensity function as it otherwise gets merged into the interpolation function of the Markov process. What I still don't really understand is, how the NumericQ interferes with the function. Does it simply "prevent" the merging of the intensity function with the `InterpolatingFunction`?

Comment: @ThomasFankhauser  Glad it works.  The NumericQ restriction limits the definition to Numeric input only. If you were to remove this, then you could put in symbolic input, say x, and the same problem would result with the rules modifying internal elements of `InterpolatingFunction`.  Including the restriction helps to ensure that the `InterpolatingFunction' is evaluated before the rules are applied.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations! You helped a lot!